# How to take reports form AVEVA E3D using C#

Tags: c#

Is there anybody, who knows how to extract reports from AVEVA E3D using C#?. For example, how to get pipe name, equipment name by using C#.

Is there any document except .NET customization guide, to read about AVEVA E3D and C#?

Comment: Hi, Rza. Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried? What did you search before asking your question?

Comment: hi, Pelicer, I want to customize AVEVA E3D design program by using C#. We take lots of reports in AVEVA E3D, and sometimes there are 1000-1500 pipes that need to taking reports. I want to extract pipe attributes to excel by just clicking on Pipe name and stating C#. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

With AVEVA E3D, you can easily extract them with the command line (using PML - Programmable Macro Langage).

You don't have to use C# but if you really want, you can have a look here :
[PDMS C#](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEHeX2ze5RxBCLvhTocWcQlLRmnPyvPuH)

Comment: Can I create Folders and Excel files using PML?

Comment: Sure, for the folder, use the syscom syntax. Into your command line on E3D, write this : " syscom | mkdir C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Example |   " . You can write any batch command inside a syscom (system command), but you can't read or use information from a syscom ! (for example, save into variable). For Excel files, well, you can but it is little more harder and I don't know your level on PML. But I can easily give you a coding for extracting into .csv files. But, you know, E3D had a lot of macro or option for extract data, even with excel files.

Comment: Thanks you, Yann, We take reports from E3D, for example, pipe name, its cad area and so on, and extract it to excel by using "reports" toolbar on E3D. But it is the long way, and takes a lot of time. I want to write a program where I can extract all this attributes into Excel just by one click.

Answer (score 0):

Write this into a .txt file :

```
-- this is a comment
-- Change the path directory, this is your output

!path=|C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\extract.csv|

-- Here you can choose between a lot of type element, like pipe or equi for the sample
-- var !c is a declaration of variable, collect is a collection of type, all equi means every equipment of my MDB (multi database).
var !c collect all equi
-- The first line of my array contains Name, you can delete this if you don't need
!tab = array()
!tab.append('Name')

-- For each values of my array !c which contains all equipment, I do this action
Do !x values !c

    -- You can select your attribute, here I choose the name
    !name = !x.dbref().name
    -- I put the result of the name into my array
    !tab.append(!name)
Enddo

!file = object file(!path)
-- I create a object file with the name of my output file, then I choose the Append option and put my array on the output file.
!file.writefile('Append', !tab)
```

Once you have save this into a .txt file, you have to call it into E3D, open E3D, open the command window and write this : "$m C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\YourMacroName.txt"

The $m call the macro, the syntax is $m PathName\FileName
You can write a macro in .txt format, or like every AVEVA macro, you can choose the .pmlmac format (pml macro). The format doesn't matter, it is just a easy way to recognize the AVEVA macro.

Comment: Sorry, I have another question, how to create excel with gridlines and add expressions to other cells and columns?

Comment: Like I said, using excel with pml is a little more harder. I don't your level about pml so I guess you will not understand my gobbledygook. You have to call the C# and using it. Use the syntax "import 'GridControl' " and "using namespace 'Aveva.Core.Presentation' ".  Then, you have to use the PmlNetControl and the container. You need a PML formation (4 days) or a software developer. For the formula, well, to be true, never use it. I prefer use a PML expression and put the value I wanted into my excel but I guess you can put some formula too. Then excel will read into.